# How to integrate paypal on website

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a paypal account but are completely new of how to set up a paypal solution on my website. I develop on my computer so the website is not up on the internet yet.

I will sell digital goods which are textfiles and ebooks.

1. I try to use the wizard: https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard
   So in step 2, this creates a button which I placed on my website including putting "paypalfunctions.php", "orderconfirm.php", "checkout.php", "cancel.php" in the rootdirectory of the website.
2. In the .php file, I have changed those to the ones in the sandbox:
   $API_UserName="xxxxxx_api1.hotmail.com";
   $API_Password="xxxxxxpassword";
   $API_Signature="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp.yxxxxxxxxx";
3. I have created a sandbox account here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications

When I click the paypal button on my website. It opens up a small window which has the same content as my actual page on the website where I clicked the paypal button. I don't understand what is happening here.

Shouldn't paypal payment processing be opened in that window?

I don't know what I am missing to start to set this up correctly?
I don't really know where to begin?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to make it so difficult. Use my example below, it is extremely simple. This will give you an idea on how things work. Go from there.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITERMNAME HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="PAYPAL-EMAIL-ACCOUNT-HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="CUSTOM FIELD HERE IF YOU WISH">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="submit" name="submit">SUBMIT</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file that contains the button does not reside in the same directory as the php files you setup your form will fail and probably render whatever your server used as a default.

```
<form action='expresscheckout.php' METHOD='POST'>
```

In this case it expects `expresscheckout.php` to reside in the same folder. You may need to adjust this, such as `/expresscheckout.php` or similar.